# Redirect the website path after logging in, not the homepage reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

The path from the email to the user's Order List page, if not logged in, will go to the login page. How to after login the page will go to the Order List page ? Currently  after logging in, the page will go to the homepage

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `goBack()` method.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
const history = useHistory()
```

and after logging in

```
history.goBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps your problem

So for the login button do this

```
<button>
   <Link
     to={{
        pathname: '/login',  // this pathname should be equal to the route that you have defined for Login page
        state: { from: 'cart' },
     }}
    >
    Login to see order list
    </Link>
</button>
```

So the above code snippet should go to be page which check if the user is logged in or not and redirect them to the login page if they are not initially logged in.

Now, in your Login.js component file
under the `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user is logged in condition) {
      let intended = history.location.state; // this history object comes react-router-dom
      if (intended) {
        history.push(intended.from);
      } 
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: This Link in the email